# Magento Go product_attribute.addOption

Tags: magento, soap, magento-go

I am using SOAP v1 of the Magento API, I am trying to add an option to an attribute.

My Code:

```
$attributeCode = "feltColor";
$optionToAdd = array(
    "Label" => array(
        array(
            "store_id" => 1,
            "value" => "Green"
        )
    ),
    "order" => 0,
    "is_default" => 0
);
```

But I keep getting the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [108] Default option value is not defined

Can't get it to work...any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a label for store_id = 0 (instead of or in addition to defining one for store_id = 1).

This is from the [docs for product_attribute.create](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttribute/product_attribute.create.html), but also holds true for product_attribute.addOption:

> Notes: The "label" value for the "store_id" value set to 0 must be
>   specified. An attribute cannot be created without specifying the label
>   for store_id=0.

If you define a label for store_id = 0, that is the default, so you don't need to define it for other store views unless you want to override the default:

```
$attributeCode = "feltColor";
$optionToAdd = array(
    "Label" => array(
        array(
            "store_id" => 0,
            "value" => "Green"
        )
    ),
    "order" => 0,
    "is_default" => 0
);
```